# Yii + Zend gdata. Youtube upload

Tags: yii, youtube-api, zend-gdata

I want to upload videos with next way:

1. I just upload file to server (as usual)
2. My server-side Yii-application takes that video and uploads it on Youtube from a special account on youTube

What do i have:

- My YouTube (google) account name and email. "name" or "name@gmail.com"
- My password
- A developer Key, which I found in Google's "Product Dashboard"
- A name of the application, which names 'myapp':

> Product Dashboard: myapp

So, I read some docs in google and decided that best way for me is to use ClientLogin auth type, because I have only one account to use and I have all necessary data. I found an example for ZendFramework's GData and I imported it into my Yii application.

I specially simplified the code just to upload one single video from /upload directory to test that it works. I expect to find a video in my YT account uploaded. Of course there is no video and here I am :-) Complete code of the action is below:

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

$yt_user = 'myYTname';
$yt_pass = 'myYTpass';
$yt_source = 'myapp';
$yt_api_key = 'veryVERYlongKEYhere';

$authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
    $username = $yt_user,
    $password = $yt_pass,
    $service = 'youtube',
    $client = null,
    $source = $yt_source,
    $loginToken = null,
    $loginCaptcha = null,
    $authenticationURL
);
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient, $yt_source, null, $yt_api_key);
$myVideoEntry = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry();
$filesource = $yt->newMediaFileSource(Yii::getpathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/videos/video.mp4');
$filesource->setContentType('video/mp4');
$filesource->setSlug('video.mp4');
$myVideoEntry->setMediaSource($filesource);
$myVideoEntry->setVideoTitle('My Test Movie');
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDescription('My Test Movie description');
$myVideoEntry->setVideoCategory('Autos');
$myVideoEntry->SetVideoTags('cars, funny');
$myVideoEntry->setVideoDeveloperTags(array('mydevtag', 'anotherdevtag'));

$uploadUrl = "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{$yt_user}/uploads";
try {
    $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $httpException) {
    echo $httpException->getRawResponseBody();
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of default code from the official example. But it doesn't work. Noone **echo** shows me information. But when I deleted try-catch, I got an error:

```
Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException
Read timed out after 10 seconds
```

Comment: UPD 1: I removed timeout exception by setting new timeout parameter in ZendHTTP class. So now my app's page is just loading loading loading and then shows nithong. No exception information and so

Comment: UPD 2: The video which i try to upload is 300 Kb size, so there must be no need to transmit the data even 10 seconds

Comment: UPD 3: I debugged my app with XDebug and found out that there is still stupid timeout exeption. 100 seconds timeout to upload a 300Kb file... There is something wrong but I can't understant what...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this problem is solved by myself :)
First of all: don't try to upload from localhost!
Then in my case I got an error, that I didn't say my dev-key! So, if you got the same error, try to change this:

```
    $newEntry = $yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry');
```

by adding the 4th parameter - extra headers:

```
$yt->insertEntry($myVideoEntry, $uploadUrl, 'Zend_Gdata_YouTube_VideoEntry', array(
    'X-GData-Key' => 'key=yourBIGbigBIGdeveloperKEYhere'
));
```

Good luck and have fun with youtube API!